# Format string with date by javascript to another format

Tags: javascript, date, format, string-formatting, date-formatting

I have string in this format:

`var date = "2012-02-12";`

I would like return the date in this format:

```
12.2.2012
```

What is the easiest way for this?
I was trying

```
var date = new Date( "2012-02-12" ).format("dd.m.yy");
```

but its returning error undefined is not a function.

Comment: This post answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Comment: No it definitely don't. They are creating date with `new Date()` function, but I already have the string and can't change it to date type variable.

Comment: without using a date formatting library you will need to manipulate the pieces as strings yourself

Comment: ´format()´ is not a native Javascript function... you must make it or use it from library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seem the shortest way is this:

```
var protocolDate = protocolDate.substr(8,2)+"."+
                   protocolDate.substr(5,2)+"."+
                   protocolDate.substr(0,4);
```

Isn't it a little bit counerproductive and frustrating that you can't use native javascript function for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = '2012-02-12';
var string = string.replace(/-/g, ".");
```

This will convert 2012-02-12 to 2012.02.12

Comment: And the reordering part? Removing leading zeros?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reformat the string, so in browsers that support ES5 Array methods:

```
'2012-02-12'.split('-').reverse().map(function(v){return Number(v)}).join('.') // 12.2.2012
```

However, you might want a function that is a little more efficient and works in even very old environments:

```
function reformatDate(s) {
  var b = s.split('-');
  return b[2] + '.' + Number(b[1]) + '.' + Number(b[0]);
}

console.log(reformatDate('2012-02-12')); // 12.2.2012
```

If you don't care about converting '02' to '2', then:

```
'2012-02-12'.split('-').reverse().join('.'); // 12.02.2012
```

will do the job. However, that format will be understood by most people as 12 February but some as 2 December whereas the first format is unambiguously the former.